# No Handler for Type Keyword declared on Field ElasticSearch 6.4.3

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I wonder what the cause is. This is the code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/olivere/elastic"
)

const (
    indexName    = "applications"
    docType      = "log"
    appName      = "myApp"
    indexMapping = `{
        "mappings" : {
            "log" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "app" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                    "message" : { "type" : "keyowrd" },
                    "time" : { "type" : "date" }
                }
            }
        }
    }`
)

type Log struct {
    App     string    `json:"app"`
    Message string    `json:"message"`
    Time    time.Time `json:"time"`
}

func main() {

    client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http://localhost:9200"))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = createIndexWithLogs(client)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // err = findAndPrintAppLogs(client)
    // if err != nil {
    //  panic(err)
    // }

}
```

I received an error, No Handler for Type Keyword declared on Field ElasticSearch 6.4.3. Based on the information that I got, ES 6.4.3 should use type keyword. I have no idea that my code is not working.

Does anyone know what the mistake is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `"keyword"` as `"keyowrd"` for `"message"` field. Corrected below:

```
{
        "mappings" : {
            "log" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "app" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                    "message" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                    "time" : { "type" : "date" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```